# Try to build swift from master branch failed

Tags: swift, compilation

swift/stdlib/public/SDK/SafariServices/SafariServices.swift:14:8: error: could not build Objective-C module '_SwiftSafariServicesOverlayShims' import *SwiftSafariServicesOverlayShims        ^ [19/388] Compiling build...vate/SwiftPrivateLibcExtras/macosx/x86*

The module _SwiftSafariServicesOverlayShims seems to be in beta Max OS 10.12.4,  I installed it and still not working( ./utils/build-script -r -t). Cannot figure out why

Comment: did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have both Xcode 8.2 and Xcode 8.3 beta (which is required for Swift compiler development) installed side-by-side, make sure you select "Xcode 8.3" in Xcode Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools.

[image: Command Line Tools]